# How to avoid Scientific Notation when importing a csv into Excel?

Tags: excel, csv, excel-import

I'm new in the Stack Overflow community and would very much appreciate any help.

I'm trying to import a csv file from the [US Energy Information](https://www.eia.gov/international/data/world/total-energy/total-energy-production?pd=44&p=004000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000f&u=0&f=A&v=mapbubble&a=-&i=none&vo=value&t=C&g=00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001&l=249-ruvvvvvfvtvnvv1vrvvvvfvvvvvvfvvvou20evvvvvvvvvvvvvvs&s=283996800000&e=1451606400000&)  (Downloadable from the "Download Options" button), except from the year column 1992 to 2014 the numbers imported are in the scientific notation.

If I try to change the format of these columns to "Number" then the numbers become "wrong" (i.e. the decimal point is shifted or deleted, E.g. :  256.5375E+13 & 27.4525E+12 then have the same amount of digits in the number and the the larger number actually becomes the smaller one (in this case)).

I'm using Windows 10 with a German system, but I have changed the decimal divider from the German system (using a comma) to the UK / US system (using a period / dot).

How can I avoid this?

Comment: How are you **import**ing the file? If you are using either Power Query or the Legacy import wizard, you've missed the setting to set the decimal/number separator to what it is in the actual file.  If you are just **open**ing the file, **don't**.

Comment: Thanks for your response Ron, I'm using Power Query Editor and I'm importing the data by going to "Data" in Excel and then clicking "from CSV". I'm not sure how to change the setting for the separator. It is strange because half of the numbers are converted into text and half are in this scientific format

Comment: The numbers it can understand based on your Windows Regional Settings get converted to numbers (although incorrectly).  The numbers it cannot stay as text.  See my answer below for a possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution if I am understanding things correctly:

After you select the CSV file from Power Query, and before you select `Load`,  select the `Transform Data` option down at the bottom:

[image]

Once in the PQ UI, right click on the relevant column header, and choose `Change Type / Using Locale` from the drop down window.

In the resultant dialog, you choose the format of the data you are inputting.  Presumeably this will be `Decimal Number` and `English (United States)`

[image]

Then choose `Close and Load` from the Main Menu, and you should be good to go.

Comment: I'll give that a try. Thanks a lot for your time and effort!

Answer (score 0):

In the ribbon select data, then get data, and then select your file, then you can change 'Data Type Detection' for 'do not detect data types', that should work.